# HTML: Logging box control?

Tags: html, controls, edit

I'm looking to have one of these in an HTML page.

[image: This thing]

F12 developer tools calls this a `wmd-edit` control. I suppose this requires some extra library (wmd).

I'm looking to have something *like* this (not using some library) filling up the entire page, and read only.. is this possible, or must I use a library?

I'm quite new to experimenting with HTML.

Comment: You can search on Google for a 'javascript rich text editor'.

Comment: @mooseman But I don't really want an editor, I want a text box that has a scroll bar and will fill up the entire page. (I will be logging to it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `<textarea>`. See http://jsfiddle.net/7YVZX/ for a demo.

Comment: This is precisely what I needed. Thanks!